# How do you merge a tag with a branch

Tags: svn, merge

I have a question about SVN,

I would like to merge a tag lets say: http://my.dev.com/svn/proj/tags/v.3.1.2 with my working copy. What is the svn command for that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN doesn't assign any special meaning to tags or to branches, they are just a convention for repository layout.  As far as SVN is concerned, they are just "copies" of particular revisions (provided you have been managing your repository according to this convention).  You should be able to merge a tag just like you would merge a branch.

Comment: @Gumpi Check out [Branching and Mergining](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) in the SVN documentation to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to merge a "Tag", you probably mean a Branch.

Check [this one](http://www.sepcot.com/blog/2007/04/SVN-Merge-Branch-Trunk)